# How to add multiple jobs into Prometheus console?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a test instance running on AWS to experience Prometheus monitoring. I've no problem with the installation of Prometheus and running some simple queries on the console of Prometheus server.

I've just added two more instances to setup node_exporter module of Prometheus to check the CPU utilization. I've also added these two nodes to the Prometheus config file. When I check with "node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes" command I can see all of the nodes. But I'd like to check the CPU utilization of all nodes in same graph. I can see only one node with the below command by typing the job name. My question is how can I add multiple jobs to below command? Or is there another way that I can check all the nodes CPU utilization in same graph?

```
100 - (avg by (instance) 
(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
```

Comment: Did you put them in the same job ? Both node should appear if you do. Or remove the job label in your example.

Comment: I've just solved this issue by adding separate nodes in the same job like you've indicated. Thank you Michael!